# Access metadata (dataannotations) in my model from t4 scaffolding templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

How can I access metadata (dataannotations attributes) in my asp.net mvc model class from a T4 scaffolding template?

I'm trying to read the ScaffoldColumn attribute in the T4 template so it should know if must render some columns in the index view

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within a T4 template you can access attributes from your model using reflection. If you take a look at the existing ASP.NET MVC 3 T4 templates you will see an example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML\Details.tt
```

The basic code involved is shown below:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in mvcHost.ViewDataType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
      if (Scaffold(prop)) {
          // ...
      }
}

bool Scaffold(PropertyInfo property) {
    foreach (object attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
        var scaffoldColumn = attribute as ScaffoldColumnAttribute;
        if (scaffoldColumn != null && !scaffoldColumn.Scaffold) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use MVC Scaffolding (http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/) and I use EnvDTE to read the ScaffoldColumn attributes instead reflection, here is an example (https://gist.github.com/1272922/cc263aac02c1916ade9720c13c1da015b4f2e9e6)